# Partial View returning as Full Page

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

my partial view is redirecting me to another page.

Index.cshtml

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js") type="text/javascript"></script>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SendChat", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "messages" }))
{
<div>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Message.Text)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Client.client_id, new { @Value = Model.Client.client_id, @class = "hidden" })
</div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Send message" />
    </div>
}

<div class="messages">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Partial/Chat.cshtml", Model.Messages);}
</div>
```

The partial view, Chat.cshtml

```
@using OPP.Web.Models
@model List<OPP.Web.Models.Message>


    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        Message message = Model[i];
        if (message.OwnershipId == 1)
        {
            <p style="text-align:right">
                @message.Text
            </p>
        }

        if (message.OwnershipId == 2)
        {
            <p style="text-align:left">
                @message.Text
            </p>
        }
    }
```

My Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SendChat(Message message, int id = 5)
        {
            WorkoutViewModel workoutViewModel = new WorkoutViewModel();
            workoutViewModel.Client = GetClient(id);
            int trainerId = workoutViewModel.Client.TrainerId ?? default(int);
            workoutViewModel.Chat = GetChat(workoutViewModel.Client.client_id, trainerId);

            message.ChatId = workoutViewModel.Chat.Id;
            if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                message.OwnershipId = 1;
            else if (User.IsInRole("Client"))
                message.OwnershipId = 2;
            List<Message> messages = new OPPDBContext().Messages.ToList();
            Message tmp = messages[messages.Count - 1];
            message.Order = tmp.Order + 1;
            message.Id = tmp.Id + 1;
            try
            {
                using (OPPDBContext context = new OPPDBContext())
                {
                    context.Messages.Add(message);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
                return PartialView("~/Views/Partial/Chat.cshtml", messages);
        }
```

It seems as if I have all the needed things in place. What could be wrong? There are green squiggly lines with no error code under the script, but that's about all. Not sure what to do.

Comment: check if `~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` was loaded. If it's not loaded browser opens partialview as full page

Comment: how do I check if it was loaded?

Comment: using developer tools of your favorite browser. On Chrome press F12 or Ctrl+Shift+j and go to Network. Make sure all .js are loaded

Comment: @MarceloVismari, this was actually the problem, I didn't put such lib in my Main Layout, thats y it gave me full page, now I added it and it working fine. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to return Index view from your controller as below:

```
return View("Index", workoutViewModel);
```